# Python function not storing in django database

Tags: python, django

I have written a function in python views.py, urls.py and models.py but it doesn't seem to store stuff in the database. Need help in order to store it back into database. I have provided the html, views.py, urls.py and models.py code

views.py:

```
@login_required
def job_status_update(request):
    status = request.GET['status']
    job_id = request.GET['Jobid'] 
    if status == 'Active':
       flag = True
    else:
       flag = False
    job = Job.objects.get(pk=job_id)
    try:
       job.active = flag
       job.save()
       return HttpResponse(status)
    except Exception as e:
       return JsonResponse(status)
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^job/status_update/?status=active&jobid=\d+', views.job_status_update),
```

models.py:

```
active = models.BooleanField(default = True)
```

html:

```
<span style="padding-left:50px;"></span>
       <b> Status</b>: {% if job.active %}
                            <b>Active</b>
                       {% else %}
                            <b>Deactive</b>
                       {% endif %}
        <span style="padding-left:140px;"></span>
       <button type="button" id ="Active" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="doTask(this.id)">Activate</button>
       <button type="button" id ="Deactive" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="doTask(this.id)">Deactivate</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
             function doTask(id){

                 $.ajax({
                     //url: '/job/status_update/?status=' + id + '&Jobid=' + {job.id},
                     url: 'job/status_update/?status=active&jobid=\d+',
                 //active = 
                     data: {
                         'csrfmiddlewaretoken': 
$('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val(),
                         'status': id,
                         'Jobid': {{job.id}}
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    complete: function (response) {
        $('#status').html(response.responseText);
        location.reload();
    },
    error: function () {
        $('#status').html('Bummer: there was an error!');
    },

});
return false;

}
      </script>
```

Comment: I think your indentation is messed up. `job = Job.objects.get(pk=job_id)` and the rest should be inside `job_status_update`, correct?

Comment: could you post the URL calling that views? the URL in `address bar`. .I want to see how to deal with it, and what are the GET parameters..

Comment: @user2100826 I don't think that's the problem, if that was it, then it wouldn't be his current issue, the code would not even work

Comment: Url in the address bar is: http://localhost:49399/job/68/dash

Comment: with that URL, you did not call the view... the url should something like URL + `job/status_update/?status=active&jobid=23`

Comment: @Lemayzeur Yeah, I wasn't trying to offer that as a solution. Just wanted to get rid of ambiguities.

Comment: If you had called that view from a template, could you post that template, please?

Comment: Should the url be the only problem?

Comment: Not really, but you need to make sure that the url has actually called the view, before trying to debug whatever it is.. however it may be the main issue... this `request.GET['status']` in your view can only receive values from arguments after `?` in URLs: `localhost:8000/job/status_update?status=blabla`. in case you don't have this parameter, your view will raise `KeyError` error

Comment: I changed the url but not my code isn't working the way it should.

Comment: Please show your template, where you call that view with the url

Comment: You mean the html code? I am really new to web development and struggle a little with the terms. Sorry

Comment: of course, really sorry, i meant your html code. please add everything related to that view, so we can help you

Comment: html code is posted

Comment: Do you get errors in the console when you visit that URL, if so what do you see?

Comment: I do not see any errors when I visit the url

Comment: The only thing I see is that in your address bar you put 'jobid' with lowercase, whereas in your view the request is looking for 'Jobid' - try changing either of these to match eachother

Comment: It's not working despite suggested edits

Comment: You haven't stated a method in your ajax call, maybe try adding 'method: "POST"'? (previously I said GET but POST would be better)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URL patterns should not include the querystring. Change it to:

```
url(r'^job/status_update/', views.job_status_update),
```

Then, in your JavaScript, you shouldn't use `jobid=\d+`. I would use your commented out line, but remove the braces around `job.id`:

```
url: '/job/status_update/?status=' + id + '&Jobid=' + job.id,
```

Answer (score 0):

Try editing your codes with the folloowing

html

```
<button type="button" data-status ="Active" class="btn btn-primary do-task" data-job="{{job.id}})">Activate</button>
<button type="button" data-status ="Deactive" class="btn btn-primary do-task" data-job="{{job.id}})">Deactivate</button>
```

**views**

```
@login_required
def job_status_update(request):
    status = request.GET.get('status')
    job_id = request.GET.get('Jobid')
    if status == 'Active':
        flag = True
    else:
        flag = False
    job = Job.objects.get(pk=job_id)
    try:
        job.active = flag
        job.save()
        return HttpResponse(status)
    except Exception as e:
        return JsonResponse(status)
```

**urls**

```
url(r'^job/status_update/', views.job_status_update),
```

**javascript**

```
$(document).on('click','.do-task',function(){
   var status = $(this).data('status'),
       id = $(this).data('job');

   $.ajax({
       url: '/job/status_update/',
       type:'get',
       data: {
          'csrfmiddlewaretoken':$('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val(),
           'status': status,
           'Jobid': id,
       }
    },
    complete: function (response) {
        $('#status').html(response.responseText);
    },
    error: function () {
        $('#status').html('Bummer: there was an error!');
    },
});
```